# Why is my code not predicting and only computes the target value

Tags: python, svm

I have this code that load_digits and uses an SVM model for predicting digits. But after fitting the model, its prediction on new values is incorrect and computes target values that do not correspond to the given input. Below is the code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

digits = datasets.load_digits()

my_OCR_model = svm.SVC(gamma = 0.001, C = 100)

X, y = digits.data[:-10], digits.target[:-10]

my_OCR_model.fit(X, y)

print(my_OCR_model.predict(X[[-6]]))
print(y[-6])

plt.imshow(digits.images[-6], cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation="nearest")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the slicing.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

digits = datasets.load_digits()

my_OCR_model = svm.SVC(gamma = 0.001, C = 100)

X, y = digits.data, digits.target # remove slicing here

my_OCR_model.fit(X, y)

print(my_OCR_model.predict(X[[-6]]))
print(y[-6])

plt.imshow(digits.images[-6], cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation="nearest")
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, if you had a good reason for slicing, keep the same data for `X`, `y`, and `images`. Use this as the last line:

```py
plt.imshow(digits.images[:-10][-6], cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation="nearest")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hello Nicolas once again, In the same category, I am giving the following funny datset to my SVM.SVC classifier: X = np.array([1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], dtype=float) AND y = np.array([3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0], dtype=float), HOWEVER, the prediction is mapping new data points greater than 4 to 7.0, Why is this happening, the same code but simpler features and labels. Thank you

Comment: SVC maximizes the margin between categories. You're giving SVC a 1D array, so basically just points on the X axis. SVC probably put a line between 3 and 4, and determined that anything greater than 4 means 7.